# Haskell: How to attach a string to elements of a list with a specific line length?

Tags: haskell, char

My knowledge of Haskell is very basic as I have just started learning in my second year of university.

I have a list of elements such as:

```
["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
```

I have a function that prints them vertically using the printStrLn function, however I want to attach a string to each end of the line. For example `if this is my string`

```
red ifthis
blue is my
green stri
yellow str
```

It would appear like this if I were to set a character length of 10 for each line.

Comment: Show us your efforts so far.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. In the first line you removed a space, in the second line you preserved it. In the 4th line I can't tell where `str` came from - I'd have expected `ng` instead.

Comment: Do you mean `yellow ing` at the end?

Comment: The examples I have used are supposed to be 10 characters in length, apologies if I have made a typo.

Comment: what would you like to happen if you run out of characters in your seed string? Would you like it to loop back and start from the beginning again?

Comment: I have tried multiple functions and all seem to fail. I've been stuck with this for quite some time now and I'm beginning to lose interest and will most likely move on to something else. I have deleted all previous attempts of code since nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can you give us a better and precise specification, please?

Comment: @Hamish I'm assuming the seed string is the string which I am passing through it? If there are less characters than list elements then it should just stop once it's finished, but if there are more characters than list elements they need to carry on making new lines of new list elements of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
extendToLength :: Int -> String -> [String] -> [String]
extendToLength n (c:cs) (s:ss)
    | n >  length s = extendToLength n cs ((s ++ [c]):ss)
    | n == length s = s : extendToLength n (c:cs) ss
    | otherwise     = undefined
extendToLength _ [] ss = ss
extendToLength _ _  [] = []
```

Which takes an `Int`, a `String` and a `[String]`, and while the first element in the `[String]` has length less than the `Int`, we take characters from the `String` and append them to it. When we hit the desired length, we move on to the next element with whatever characters we have left.

```
> extendToLength 10 "this is my string" ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
["redthis is", "blue my st", "greenring", "yellow"]

> extendToLength 10 "this is my longer string" ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
["redthis is", "blue my lo", "greennger ", "yellowstri"]
```

If you want a buffer of a single space before any characters are appended, you can first apply `map (++ " ")` on your list of strings.

```
> extendToLength 10 "this is my string" (map (++ " ") ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"])
["red this i", "blue s my ", "green stri", "yellow ng"]
```

EDIT: FYI an error is thrown if a `String` is found exceeding the specified length.

Answer (score 0):

This code work in the way that you describe for this case, but you should change the base cases for get your desired answers in that cases:

```
cutWord :: String -> Int -> (String, String)
cutWord "" _ = ("", "")
cutWord xs 0 = ("", xs)
cutWord (x:xs) n = ((x:s1), s2)
    where (s1, s2) = cutWord xs (n-1)

appendWord :: [String] -> String -> Int -> [String]
appendWord [] _ _ = []
appendWord (xs:xss) ys n = (xs ++ " " ++ s1) : (appendWord xss s2 n)
    where (s1, s2) = cutWord ys (n - (length xs + 1))
```